# Copying elements from a NSDictionary to an object returned by a method

Tags: objective-c, copy, nsdictionary

I’m calling a JSON service, from which I get this:

```
JSON=__NSCFDictionary * 0x0c3a1310 3 key/value pairs
```

`description` is:

```
Printing description of JSON:
{
    codigo = 0;
    datos =     (
                {
            datalle = "Ahora podr\U00e1s copiar y pegar el RFC y la raz\U00f3n social del cliente.";
            datalletop = "Ahora podr\U00e1s copiar y pegar el RFC y la raz\U00f3n social del cliente.";
            "etiqueta_modulo" = "Administraci\U00f3n de clientes";
            modulo = "ADMIN_CLIENTES";
            seccion = SERVICIOS;
            "titulo_cambio" = Copiar;
            urlimagen = "images/novedades/adm.png";
        },
                {
            datalle = "En caso de que alg\U00fan usuario est\U00e9 inhabilitado para comisionarse, se mostrar\U00e1 un mensaje.";
            datalletop = "En caso de que alg\U00fan usuario est\U00e9 inhabilitado para comisionarse, se mostrar\U00e1 un mensaje.";
            "etiqueta_modulo" = Comisionate;
            modulo = COMISIONATE;
            seccion = SERVICIOS;
            "titulo_cambio" = Bloqueo;
            urlimagen = "images/novedades/comisionate.png";
        },
                {
            datalle = "Ya puedes enviar el recibo fiscal en formato XML.";
            datalletop = "Ya puedes enviar el recibo fiscal en formato XML.";
            "etiqueta_modulo" = "Impresi\U00f3n y env\U00edo de fianzas y recibos";
            modulo = IMPRESION;
            seccion = SERVICIOS;
            "titulo_cambio" = "Recibo en XML";
            urlimagen = "images/novedades/impresion.png";
        },
                {
            datalle = "Es un nuevo m\U00f3dulo que permitir\U00e1 subir documentos a la aplicaci\U00f3n a partir del carrete de fotos del iPad, sustituyendo la aplicaci\U00f3n Integrador.";
            datalletop = "Es un nuevo m\U00f3dulo que permitir\U00e1 subir documentos a la aplicaci\U00f3n a partir del carrete de fotos del iPad, ...";
            "etiqueta_modulo" = "Carga de documentos";
            modulo = INTEGRADOR;
            seccion = SERVICIOS;
            "titulo_cambio" = "Nuevo m\U00f3dulo";
            urlimagen = "images/novedades/cargadoc.png";
        },
                {
            datalle = "Ya puedes personalizar el rango de fechas entre 1 d\U00eda y 1 a\U00f1o. ";
            datalletop = "Ya puedes personalizar el rango de fechas entre 1 d\U00eda y 1 a\U00f1o. ";
            "etiqueta_modulo" = Exportador;
            modulo = EXPORTADOR;
            seccion = "INTELIGENCIA DE NEGOCIOS";
            "titulo_cambio" = "Rango de fechas";
            urlimagen = "images/novedades/exportador.png";
        },
                {
            datalle = "En la secci\U00f3n de detalle de este m\U00f3dulo, encontrar\U00e1s la opci\U00f3n de filtrar la informaci\U00f3n seg\U00fan la moneda.";
            datalletop = "En la secci\U00f3n de detalle de este m\U00f3dulo, encontrar\U00e1s la opci\U00f3n de filtrar la informaci\U00f3n seg\U00fan la moneda.";
            "etiqueta_modulo" = Renovaciones;
            modulo = RENOVACIONES;
            seccion = "INTELIGENCIA DE NEGOCIOS";
            "titulo_cambio" = "Filtro por moneda";
            urlimagen = "images/novedades/ren_cancelaciones.png";
        },
                {
            datalle = "En el reporte de Mezcla de cartera por ramos encontrar\U00e1s un scroll para poder ver m\U00e1s informaci\U00f3n.";
            datalletop = "En el reporte de Mezcla de cartera por ramos encontrar\U00e1s un scroll para poder ver m\U00e1s informaci\U00f3n.";
            "etiqueta_modulo" = Ventas;
            modulo = VENTAS;
            seccion = "INTELIGENCIA DE NEGOCIOS";
            "titulo_cambio" = "Mejora en la visualizaci\U00f3n";
            urlimagen = "images/novedades/ventas.png";
        },
                {
            datalle = "\b<ul><li>Mis clientes. Mundo Aserta hace la inteligencia de negocio por ti, permiti\U00e9ndote enfocarte en lo m\U00e1s importante de tu cartera. \U00bfC\U00f3mo? Analizando de primera vista las ventas, primas por cobrar, reclamaciones y renovaciones de tus 20 principales clientes.</li><li>Programas de proveedores. Consulta la informaci\U00f3n a detalle de cada uno de los programas de tus clientes</li><li>Movimientos. Realiza endosos de aumento a tus p\U00f3lizas de fianzas desde este m\U00f3dulo. Ya puedes realizar tambi\U00e9n cancelaci\U00f3n, disminuci\U00f3n y anula y sustituye de fianza y recibo. </li><li>Podr\U00e1s recibir notificaciones a trav\U00e9s de alertas sobre los movimientos que est\U00e1n en proceso de autorizaci\U00f3n, liberaci\U00f3n o impresi\U00f3n.</li><li>Tablero de control. Te mostrar\U00e1 tus principales indicadores como son: comportamiento de ventas; reclamaciones pagadas, recibidas y recuperadas; primas por cobrar por antig\U00fcedad y d\U00edas cartera; responsabilidades vigentes para cancelar o renovar</li><li>Emisi\U00f3n de fianzas en programas globales de fianzas vehiculares. Ya puedes emitir estas fianzas desde este nuevo m\U00f3dulo</li><li>Genera tu token para poder entrar en modo fuera de l\U00ednea y accesar a los m\U00f3dulos de inteligencia de negocios, Espacio Aserta y Campus Aserta</li></ul>";
            datalletop = "\b<ul><li>Mis clientes. Mundo Aserta hace la inteligencia de negocio por ti, permiti\U00e9ndote enfocarte en lo m\U00e1s ...";
            "etiqueta_modulo" = General;
            modulo = GENERAL;
            seccion = GENERAL;
            "titulo_cambio" = General;
            urlimagen = "images/novedades/general.png";
        },
                {
            datalle = "<ul><li>En caso de que existan fallas de procesamiento de informaci\U00f3n en los sistemas, la secci\U00f3n de Inteligencia de negocios ser\U00e1 bloqueada</li><li>Ya puedes copiar y pegar cualquier dato de la secci\U00f3n Inteligencia de negocios.</li><li>Ahora podr\U00e1s enviar por correo reportes de la secci\U00f3n Inteligencia de negocios sin l\U00edmite de resultados.</li><li>En esta secci\U00f3n, ya podr\U00e1s filtrar la informaci\U00f3n utilizando m\U00e1s de un filtro simult\U00e1neamente.</li></ul>\n";
            datalletop = "<ul><li>En caso de que existan fallas de procesamiento de informaci\U00f3n en los sistemas, la secci\U00f3n de Inteligencia de ...";
            "etiqueta_modulo" = Generales;
            modulo = GENERAL;
            seccion = GENERAL;
            "titulo_cambio" = "Mejoras en toda la aplicaci\U00f3n";
            urlimagen = "images/novedades/general.png";
        }
    );
    mensaje = EXITO;
}
(lldb)
```

I have this method:

```
+(dhNovedades*)parsear:(NSDictionary*) pdicDatos
{
    dhNovedades *novedades;
    novedades.mensaje = [pdicDatos objectForKey:@"mensaje"];
    novedades.novedades = [pdicDatos objectForKey:@"datos"];

    return novedades;
}
```

and I pass it the resulting JSON `NSDictionary` in order to get a `dhNovedades` object, which is defined like this:

```
@interface dhNovedades : NSObject
{
    NSString *login;
    NSString *id_sesion;
    NSMutableArray *novedades;
    NSString *mensaje;
}
```

The problem I’m having is with the `objectForKey` method of the `NSDictionary`: the properties of the `dhNovedades` object don’t get assigned, and when I evaluate those expressions I get:

```
[pdicDatos objectForKey:@"mensaje"] = Invalid Expression
```

I reviewed the contents of the `NSDictionary` `pdicDatos`, and the three elements are of type `__NSCFString`; I guess that has something to do with the problem, since I'm assigning

```
novedades.mensaje = [pdicDatos objectForKey:@"mensaje"]; //mensaje is a NSString
novedades.novedades = [pdicDatos objectForKey:@"datos"]; //novedades.novedades is a NSMutableArray
```

I read somewhere that this might have to do with the memory management of `NSDictionary` — something like the objects that I’m trying to get not being retained — but
I’m pretty new to this and have no idea of what the problem might be, so please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: OMG... spanish... difficult to understand!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `+parsear:`, you're not actually instantiating an instance of `dhNovedades`. You should be doing this in the first line:

```
dhNovedades *novedades = [[dhNovedades alloc] init];
```

That would be a start toward resolving your issues, since we don't know from what you've provided how your properties or accessors for `dhNovedades` are set up.

One other thing, apropos of nothing: Your class names should be capitalized. If the "dh" is meant to be a prefix, both letters should be capitalized.

Comment: This kind of errors make me question my carrer choice, ha ha haaawww. BTW, I'm in my way to refactor those class names (among other things), I can only say they were there before I was here.

Comment: No criticism intended; I was only saying. And we all make mistakes.